# copy n bits at given position from x to y in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am learning C and I am still a very beginner.

My problem is the following. I have one unisgned int x and one unsigned int y. I would like to copy n bits from position p from x to the same position on y. I found some similar problems but not in C and most of the time the problem is slightly different if one takes the most right or left bits. I would also like to find a solution not depending on integer representation on the machine.

Here is what I did

```
unsigned fix_bits(unsigned x, unsigned y, int n, int p)
{
    unsigned u1,u2,u3,u4,x1,y1,yf;
    u1 = ~0; /*vector of 1*/
    u2 = (u1>>n); /*0 from 0 to n-1 and 1s*/
    u3 = ~(u2);/*1 from 0 to n-1 and 0s*/
    u4 = u3>>p;/*0 from 0 to p-1, n 1 from p to p+n+1 and 0s*/
    x1 = (x & u4);/*only keep n bits of x from position p*/
    y1 = (y | u4);/*set y bit  from p to (p+n+1) to 1, rest remains unchanged (0 | bit = bit)*/
    yf = (x1 | y1);
    return yf;
}
```

But it does not work:

The result of placing 2 bits at position 3 of 28 to 32 is 402653216

Does someone knows what am I doing wrong ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Firstly, the positions count from the most significant bit. That's perfectly possible, but unusual. Secondly, your mux is broken. Try `y1 = y & ~u4`

Comment: What is the expected result of placing 2 bits at position 3 of 28 to 32?

Comment: I am assuming from viewing the results in binary (see illustration below), that you just need to operate from LSB rather than MSB.  Is that a correct assumption?  (i.e. instead of position 5 being 5 bits from left, start at 5 bits from the right)

Comment: Assuming you really wanted to work from the LSB, and count from position toward LSB (i.e. toward the right)?

Comment: I'm just s*&#pid I guess... The solution proposed below is probably right but I wanted to use only AND and OR so actually I used MSB representation operations while having in my mind the LSB representation... All the comments are right and helping. I would like to thank everyone !

Only by inverting left shift with right shift did what I wanted !

Comment: In the spirit of 'teach a man to fish', read [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).

Answer (score 2):

***Regarding the problem:*** *copy n bits from position p from x to the same position on y*

Results with your code just as it is in the OP :

```
unsigned int x = 0xffffffff;
unsigned int y = 0x00000000;
unsigned int z = 0x00000000;
z = fix_bits(x, y, 5, 5);
```

[image]

It looks like you are operating from the wrong end of the target number.  Change your logic to work from the right (LSB), instead of the left (MSB).

Try this:

```
unsigned fix_bits(unsigned x, unsigned y, int n, int p)
{
    unsigned a, b, c, d, e;
    int mask;
    //Get mask
    mask = ((1<<(n))-1)<<(p-n); //[edit] corrected, was ...<<p, is ...<<(p-n)
    //apply mask to destination, 
    //XOR that with repositioned, BITwise NOTed source and apply mask
    /*so you can do these steps:
    a = mask|y;
    b = ~x;
    c = b<<p;
    d = c&mask;
    e = d^a;

    return e;*/
    //or do this one:  
    return ((mask&(~x<<p))^(mask|y)); //same thing
}
```

For the shown inputs, the example output is below:

```
unsigned int x = 0xffffffff;
unsigned int y = 0xf0000000;
unsigned int z = 0x00000000;

z = fix_bits(x, y, 3, 20);
```

[image]

Results after correction to mask (***was*** `<<p`, ***is*** `<<(p-n)`):

[image]

Comment: It's only fine in some cases, not in general.

Comment: @harold - Sorry, I did not mean to imply it was fine at all.  Merely pointing out that OP was probably getting unexpected values because his algorithm was working from the MSB rather than the LSB.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the mask wrong. Try:

```
unsigned mask = ((1 << n) - 1) << p;
return (y & ~mask) | (x & mask);
```

Comment: This places the mask starting at _p+n_, should it not be `((1 << n) - 1) << p-n;`

Comment: @ryker I'm assuming that position 0 is the LSB and that the intent is to move bits `p` through `p + n - 1`. You're right that the code needs to be adapted if you intend `n` and `p` to mean something different.

Comment: Yes, never did fully get what OP original intent was.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So my final working solution is just

```
unsigned fix_bits(unsigned x, unsigned y, int n, int p)

{

    unsigned u1,u2,u3,u4,x1,y1,yf;
    u1 = ~0; /*vector of 1*/
    u2 = (u1<<n); /*0 from 0 to n-1 and 1s*/
    u3 = ~(u2);/*1 from 0 to n-1 and 0s*/
    u4 = u3<<p;/*0 from 0 to p-1, n 1 from p to p+n+1 and 0s*/
    x1 = (x & u4);/*only keep n bits of x from position p*/
    y1 = (y | u4);/*set y bit  from p to (p+n+1) to 1, rest remains unchanged (0 | bit = bit)*/
    yf = (x1 | y1);
    return yf;

}
```

And then

x = 28 = [0 0 ... 0 1 1 1 0]

y = 32 = [0 0 ... 1 0 0 0 0]

fix_bits(28,32,2,3) /*placing two bits at position 3 from 28 to 32*/

Outputs

z = 56 = [0 0 ... 1 1 1 0 0]

Answer (score 0):

I needed a similar function for building an NES emulator.  Using the solution by @ryyker, I created a slightly more general function for `uint16_t`.  It could probably be optimized.  It should also meet the original poster's requirements when `source_pos = dest_pos`.

Perhaps someone brought here while looking to solve the general case will find this helpful.

```
/*                                                                                                                                                                  
 * This was fun to figure out.  Copy num bits at source_pos from source
 * into dest at dest_pos.  Positions start at 0, the LSB.
 */
uint16_t set_bits(uint16_t source, uint16_t dest, int num, int source_pos, int dest_pos)                                                                            
{
    unsigned long mask = ((1UL<<(num))-1UL)<<(source_pos);

    if (dest_pos >= source_pos) {
            return (dest & (~(mask << dest_pos))) | ((source & mask) << dest_pos);
    }

    return (dest & (~(mask >> (source_pos - dest_pos)))) | ((source & mask) >> (source_pos - dest_pos));
```

}

Comment: This doesn't work if `int` is 16-bit and `num + source_pos >= 15` because you shift into the sign bit (or shift by greater than the width of the type), which is undefined behaviour. A quick fix would be to make `mask` be `unsigned long` and change `1` to `1UL`.  This will probably generate the same code on your system, but the code will now work properly on other systems.

Comment: Thanks for the code review!  I've implemented your fix to my code.  My text task: bring my knowledge of the C spec up to snuff!

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char
copy_Nbits(unsigned char num_S, unsigned char num_D, char start_off, char end_off)
{
    unsigned char u1 = 0;
    unsigned char u2 = 0;

    u1 = ~u1;
    u1 = (u1 >> ((8 * sizeof(num_S)) - 1 - end_off + start_off));
    u1 = (u1 << start_off);
    u2 = u1;
    u2 &= num_S;

    u1 = ~u1;
    u1 &= num_D;

    return (u1 | u2);
}
```